# How to retrieve only lookup id in Sharepoint with JSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to get list items from a SharePoint list with specific fields only.
The list contains lookup fields to other lists and I need the LookupId only for these.

I know two cases to narrow down the returned fields.

The first is with CAML. I can use the LookupId="TRUE" option to suppress the LookupValue in this case, but the server returns other system fields (eg. Modified By, Created By, etc.) which I don't need to.

The second is using 'Include' in ClientContext.load method. In this case the server not sends the system fields but I don't know how to specify (if possible) to receive the LookupId only for lookup fields.
I tried several versions in Include (project.id, projectId, project.lookupId, project.Inlude(id)) but none of them worked.

So, my question is:  how to retrieve only specified fields of a SharePoint list with LookupIds only for lookup fields?

Answer (score 4):

You were very close to archive the desired result, you need to combine two techniques in  order to retrieve *id part of lookup value* as demonstrated below:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.getItems(createLookupQuery('Project'));
ctx.load(items,'Include(Project)'); 
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
       if(items.get_count() > 0){
           var item = items.getItemAtIndex(0);
           console.log(item.get_fieldValues()['Project'].get_lookupId());   
       }
   }, 
   function(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message()); 
   });


function createLookupQuery(lookupFieldName){
      var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
      qry.set_viewXml("<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='" + lookupFieldName + "' LookupId='TRUE' /></ViewFields></View>");
      return qry;
}
```

- In CAML query we specify attribute `LookupId='TRUE'` to retrieve Id
  part of lookup field value
- since CAML query includes also system field values, we utilize
  [`SP.ClientContext.load method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903.aspx) to return specific field value
  only

Comment: It is not possible to combine the Include field selector in the load method with the ViewFields in the CAML query as I know. But will try it...

Comment: It is supported to combine both techniques

Comment: I'm getting “Value does not fall within expected range” error if put fields in ViewFields and Include.

Comment: Can you share your CAML query? The list of fields for `ViewFields` should **correspond** to fields in expression for `load` function like demonstrated in my example (for one field only), which in turn is working properly for me.

Comment: It is very intresting. I tried to minimize fields and removed the query from CAML and it worked. I then put back all the fields id still worked. Put back the query and it still works. Maybe I made a typo. Thank you for the solution.
Anyway, I still get the lookup fields in FieldLookupValue objects with the LookupValue eqal to LookupId. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior,  both get_lookupValue() and get_lookupId() function will return LookupId (as string and integer value types)

Answer (score 1):

> how to retrieve only specified fields of a SharePoint list with
>   LookupIds only for lookup fields?

The question is a bit unclear, but assuming you want to fetch the lookup id, you can do as follows.

Suppose you've retrieved the `SP.ListItem` with JSOM and stored it in to a variable, your lookup field will be representeed by a [SP.LookupFieldValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246742.aspx) object.

You can access it from the retrieved `item` object as below.

```
var lookupFieldValue = item.get_item('FieldName');
var lookupId = lookupFieldValue.get_lookupId();
```

Comment: To be clear, I need only the LookipId from the lookup field and don't need the LookupValue (to minimize the data the server sends).